JavaScript heap out of memory during npm install on Azure pipeline
I'm recently updating my angular projects from angular 16 to angular 17. npm install works perfectly with angular 17 on my laptop. But on Azure pipeline, it throws an error saying:-
 "FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory".

How can I solve this?
In one repo, I solved this issue by changing "npm install" as a script to "npm install" as an in-built task: Npm@1.
But it doesn't work in another repo. I also removed package-lock.json before npm install but it didn't help.

Hooyin Ni, Check if the solution below works for you?

You need to increase memory allocation for your nodejs by using the script below in your yaml code to remove the heap limitation:-
trigger:
  - main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - task: NodeTool@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '18.x'
    displayName: 'Install Node.js'

  - script: |
      NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=4096" npm install
    displayName: 'npm install with increased memory'

  - script: |
      npm cache clean --force
    displayName: 'Clear npm cache'

  - script: |
      npm install --only=dev
    displayName: 'Install dev dependencies'

Output:-

Reference my SO Answer where I have applied the command to increase node space
